# List all the Junit Test Cases in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, testcase

I'm using Junit with Eclipse. I have created test cases for few of the methods in my project. Is there any way/plugin to find the list of classes for which the test cases have been created(so that I need not manually check whether test cases created for all methods)?

Answer (score 3):

You should look into using [Code coverage tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Code_Coverage_Tools), that are designed to do exactly this by telling you for instance:

- which lines are covered by your tests
- which branches of loops, ifs, switches, etc. are covered by your tests

Answer (score 1):

More unit plug-in decorates all classes for which test classes are written.
[Check here](http://moreunit.sourceforge.net/).

---

### Using code coverage tools:

> If used code coverage tools, then user has to run this(Ex:**Eclemma**) tool again and again to cover all use cases and merge the results of each run to check the method coverage.This takes more time.
>
> Even this procedure is automated then also user has to open all source files to check whether the method is covered or not. [See coverage view](http://www.eclemma.org/userdoc/coverageview.html).
>
> If the method is marked as 100% coverage that doesn’t mean that test case was written for that method **separately**. Because other method may called this method internally.
>
> So using code coverage tool it is not possible to decide whether test cases were written for all the methods of all the classes.